# Heroku pull postgres database to local failed with unrecognized data block type (0)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pull, heroku-ci

I connected to heroku postgres database with pgadmin and created a simple table that has two simple columns:

```
id - bigint identity 
name - text
```

and simple two rows:

```
id   name
1    name1
2    name2
```

When I execute the command

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb1234 --app nameless-dusk-05113
```

I get the error:

```
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
 !    pg_restore errored with 1
```

I checked postgres local and remote versions, they are the same.
Local version:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.5

pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.5
```

Remote version:

```
heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           5/20
PG Version:            12.5
Created:               2021-01-07 07:29 UTC
Data Size:             8.2 MB
Tables:                1
Rows:                  2/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-spherical-97042
```

remote pg_restore version:

```
heroku run pg_restore --version
Running pg_restore --version on ⬢ nameless-dusk-05113... up, run.7775 (Free)
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`heroku pg:pull` is supposed to automate a slightly more manual process described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export.

Although I ran into the same error with `heroku pg:pull`, the more manual process worked. Specifically,

```
$ heroku pg:backups:capture
$ heroku pg:backups:download  # this creates a file latest.dump in your current directory
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d mydatabasename latest.dump
```

If `mydatabasename` doesn't already exist, you'll have to create it before running `pg_restore`.

```
$ createdb -U postgres mydatabasename
```